# Excel VBA: Cycle through Checkboxes by name, and also through similarly named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox, userform

I have the following in my userform:

```
CheckBox11 CheckBox12 CheckBox13 CheckBox14 CheckBox15
CheckBox21 CheckBox22 CheckBox23 CheckBox24 CheckBox25
```

Also, in my excel I have following named ranges:

```
range11 range12 range13 range14 range15
range21 range22 range23 range24 range25
```

I want to loop through each of the checkboxes, and in case of True, do something with the range, Say copy-paste the corresponding ranges to another location.

I have a nested For loop, `i = 1 to 2`
and `j = 1 to 5`

and then inside another long variable `nm = i*10+j`

now I want to refer to the CheckBox and Range with nm.

Any other alternative is also welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `Me.Controls("CheckBox" & nm)` and `Range("range" & nm)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub Test()
For Each objControl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
If TypeName(objControl.Object) = "CheckBox" And objControl.Object = True Then
rngName = Replace(objControl.Name, "CheckBox", "range")
Range(rngName).Select
MsgBox rngName & " selected"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The sub will select the named range at each selected CheckBox (True value).
But that's if the checkbox is an ActiveX and the named range is within the same sheet where the checkboxes are.

Anyway, you can just change the `Range(rngName).Select .... MsgBox rngName & " selected"` line to whatever process you want to do with the corresponding named range.

Below if the checkbox is in a Userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" And ctrl = True Then
rngName = Replace(ctrl.Name, "CheckBox", "range")
Range(rngName).Select
MsgBox rngName & " selected"
End If
Next
End Sub
```